# Alias Column in Laravel Scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Here is my Model Scope

```
public function scopeUser($query, $user_id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->select(['_id', 'company_name', 'location', 'template_id', 'current_theme_id', 'site_url', 'site_path', 'addons']);
}
```

What i want is to us `theme_id` as alias in place of `current_theme_id`

Tried already searching for solution but all of theme were based on DB queries.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get when you use the answers below such as `current_theme_id as theme_id`. Can you post the exception and the query which is generated? `Model::user(1)->toSql()`

Comment: I do not get any error but in the result there is no `current_theme_id` or `theme_id` present. the records are being returned fine

Comment: Rather than `->get()` echo `->toSql()` on your query to see what it's actually running and update the question so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "current_theme_id" with "current_theme_id as theme_id" as given below.

```
public function scopeUser($query, $user_id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->select(['_id', 'company_name', 'location', 'template_id', 'current_theme_id as theme_id', 'site_url', 'site_path', 'addons']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add:

```
protected $appends = ['theme_id']

public function getThemeIdAttribute()
{
    return $this->current_theme_id;
}
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: but this will apply every time ? I just want it to rename at this query not every

Comment: Then this isn't the solution you need. You'll have to create a repository for your model and add your query. However, it will still involve modifying the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment:

> I do not get any error but in the result there is no `current_theme_id` or `theme_id` present. the records are being returned fine

I doubt the column `current_theme_id` is listed in your Model's `$fillable` property. If it is already listed, try the below suggestion.

This might just be a work around, using `selectRaw` method

```
public function scopeUser($query, $user_id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                 ->selectRaw('*, current_theme_id AS theme_id')
                 ->select([
                     '_id', 'company_name', 'location',
                     'template_id', 'site_url', 'site_path',
                     'addons', 'theme_id'
                 ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
public function scopeUser($query, $user_id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
   ->selectRaw('_id, company_name, location, template_id, current_theme_id as theme_id, site_url, site_path, addons');
}
```

Comment: Even though it might answer OP's question, it's best to explain what you did. Like you can use this code, for example what I did is add "AS" to create an alias for the column and so on.